# Get character at current position within TinyMCE when the input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Right now i can detect if the input changes in the TinyMCE Editor, but i can't seem to figure out how to get what was changed/typed.

```
setup:function(editor) {
    editor.on('input', function(e){
        //pseudo condition
        if (this.value === 'X') {
            console.log('You type X', e);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like it to reach the console.log if X is typed into the editor, and maybe a way to move from that position back and forward just in case i have read pre and post text from that specific position.

The purpose of this is to be able to trigger another action when a specific word is typed into the editor like for suggestions and such.

Comment: If you want an autocomplete functionality why don't you use [jQuerys autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: It's not really what im looking for, i need this to listen to specific commands like {link: then it should popup with a group of registered links and once i select one of the links, it will place the id of the link and close the placeholder like {link:32} for templating purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `slice()` function in JavaScript that returns you a "slice" of a string. You can use it to determine (for example) what are the last 6 characters in your input.

Example:

```
setup:function(editor) {
    editor.on('input', function(e){
        if (this.value.slice(this.value.length - 6, this.value.length) === '{link:') {
            //Do magic
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did that in the beginning just a tad different with  

    (this.value.substr(this.value.length - 9)
  
But this.value doesn't work inside TinyMCE, there you only have the getContent from the TinyMCE API. :D  

My current issue it to get the content around the cursor position within TinyMCE.  

The problem with getContents is that it gets all the content, and i cant search for the {link: part as there might be several links within the article.